# Can't create a dynamic view in ClearCase application under Windows

Tags: clearcase

I have a problem to create a dynamic view from command line in ClearCase application (under Windows Vista).

```
C:\Users\xxx>
cleartool mkview -tag xxx -host xxx 
-hpath C:\ccviews\xxx.vws -gpath C:\ccviews\xxx.vws C:\ccviews\xxx.vws

cleartool: Warning: Config spec OK, but unable to tell view server to load.
cleartool: Warning: View server should be restarted.
cleartool: Error: Set configuration spec of c:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\

default_config_spec failed: view storage directory or control files unavailable

---
additional information may be present in the view server host's view log

cleartool: Error: unable to remove C:\ccviews\xxx.vws: 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

cleartool: Error: C:\ccviews\xxx.vws: Permission denied

cleartool: Error: Unable to create view "C:\ccviews\xxx.vws".
```

---

According to IBM the solution is :

VOB and view storage created on a Windows system must be created from the Windows Operating System

I have checked it but everything looks fine.

Could you please help me here? Any ideas, tips? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Please provide the link to the "IBM solution" you have read.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an issue with the ClearCase services (albd, lock manager).

Try:

- start / settings/ control panel / ClearCase > stop/restart ClearCase services
- or a full reboot, before trying again a mkview.

Comment: I have tried to stop and start the ClearCase services from control panel but it says that user is not the admin. However, the user has admin rights... weird...

Comment: @Radek I understand. Try a reboot.

Comment: it's realy helps.
But i can't find ClearCase in Control Panel and going to start cc.cpl

Comment: @yuri you can find the ClearCase service with services.msc

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to let you know that I fixed the problem.
It was related to wrong installation of ClearCase application (installation of wrong ClearCase and then wrong uninstallation and installation of correct version).

When I was looking at "Control Panel -> ClearCase" then everything looked fine. Output from ccdoctor was also correct. However, when I opened ClearCase settings from "CMD -> cc.cpl" then I noticed that registry server was incorrect.

Pretty weird error and behavior. Especially that output from ccdoctor was fine. Anyway, it's fine now.

Thanks a lot for tips!